# Selecting an element's parent's previous sibling's child - traversing elements

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, tree-traversal

I know the title is a bit possessive but I had no better way to word it correctly.

#### Generated HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="orderResultTabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#5423788082" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="false">5423788082</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#5424163999" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="false">5424163999</a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

I have a set of bootstrap tabs that get appended after an ajax call. However, after each call I'd like the previous tab to be set to inactive. Making the newest tab the focus. Essentially all previous a.nav-links should have their active class removed after each ajax call.

#### JS:

```
$("#orderResultTabs > li > a:last").parent().prevAll().siblings().find(".active").removeClass("active");
$("#orderResultTabs > li > a:last").addClass("active");
```

#### Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "orders",
        data: "order_id=" + orderID + "&flag=" + flag,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // var table = $("#orderOutput");
            var tabNav = $("#orderResultTabs");
            var tabContent = $('.tab-content');
            for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                orderID = data[i].orders_id;
                orderLoop(i, data, tabNav, orderID, tabContent);
            }
            $('.loader').hide(); //hide loader
            $('.clear').show();
            $("#orderResultTabs > li > a:last").parent().prevAll().siblings().find(".active").removeClass("active");

            $("#orderResultTabs > li > a:last").addClass("active");
            $("input[type=orderID]").val("");
            $('#ordersOutput').show();

        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert('error');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

#### orderLoop()

```
function orderLoop(i, data, tabNav, orderID, tabContent) {
    tabNav.append("<li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link active' data-toggle='tab' href=#" + data[i].orders_id + " role='tab' aria-controls='home' aria-expanded='false'>" + data[i].orders_id + "</a></li>");

    for (var j = data.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        tabContent.append("<div class='tab-pane fade' id=" + data[j].orders_id + " role='tabpanel'><div class='tab'><div class='col'><table class='table table-sm table-responsive' id='orderOutput'></table><form role='form'><button id='viewOrderItems' value='NO ORDER ID' type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block'>View Order Items</button></form></div></div></div>");
        var table = $(".tab-pane#" + data[j].orders_id + " > .tab > .col > table");
        table.append("<tr><th>ADDRESS ID</th><td>" + data[j].address+ "</td></tr>");
        table.append("<tr><th>CURRENCY</th><td>" + data[j].currency + "</td></tr>");
        table.append("<tr><th>MEMBER ID</th><td>" + data[j].member+ "</td></tr>");
        table.append("<tr><th>STORE ID</th><td>" + data[j].store+ "</td></tr>");
        table.append("<tr><th>TIMEPLACED</th><td>" + moment(data[j].timeplaced).format("MMMM D, YYYY @ h:mm A") + "</td></tr>");
        table.append("<tr><th>TOTAL ADJUSTMENT</th><td>$" + data[j].adjust+ "</td></tr>");
        table.append("<tr><th>TOTAL PRODUCT</th><td>$" + data[j].prod+ "</td></tr>");
        table.append("<tr><th>TOTAL SHIPPING</th><td>$" + data[j].totalshipping + "</td></tr>");
        table.append("<tr><th>TOTAL TAX</th><td>$" + data[j].tax+ "</td></tr>");
        table.append("<tr><th>TOTAL SHIPPING TAX</th><td>$" + data[j].shiptax+ "</td></tr>");
        table.append("<tr><th>TYPE</th><td>" + data[j].type + "</td></tr>");
        var button = $(".tab-pane#" + data[j].orders_id + " > .tab > .col > form > button");
        button.val(data[i].orders_id);
        $('.nav-tabs a:last').tab('show');

    }
}
```

If anyone has ideas on how to do this, I'd love to hear from you.

---

### After @varlogtim's suggestions:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="orderResultTabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#5423788082" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="false">5423788082</a>
            </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#5424163999" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="false">5424163999</a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

When I click, the list item goes active, the tab content is shown, but the nav-link remains inactive. I've attempted to the following:

```
$(".nav-link").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

### After commenting: // $("#orderResultTabs > li:last").addClass("active");

#### Initial:

```
<div id="ordersOutput">
      <div role="tabpanel">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="orderResultTabs" role="tablist">
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content clearfix">
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

#### First Run:

```
<div id="ordersOutput" style="display: block;">
      <div role="tabpanel">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="orderResultTabs" role="tablist">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link **active**" data-toggle="tab" href="#5423788082" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="false">5423788082</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content clearfix">
                  <div class="tab-pane **active**" id="5423788082" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="tab">
                              <div class="col">
                                    <table class="table table-sm table-responsive" id="orderOutput">
                                    </table>
                                    <form role="form">
                                    </form>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

#### Second Run:

```
<div id="ordersOutput" style="display: block;">
      <div role="tabpanel">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="orderResultTabs" role="tablist">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#idAlpha" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="false">idAlpha</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link **active**" data-toggle="tab" href="#idBeta" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="false">idBeta</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content clearfix">
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="idAlpha" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="tab">
                              <div class="col">
                                    <table class="table table-sm table-responsive" id="orderOutput">
                                    </table>
                                    <form role="form" lpformnum="2">
                                    </form>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane **active**" id="idBeta" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="tab">
                              <div class="col">
                                    <table class="table table-sm table-responsive" id="orderOutput">
                                    </table>
                                    <form role="form">
                                    </form>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

#### After Second Run - When I click the first tab:

Notice that even though I have activated/clicked the (.nav-link) for the first tab (#idAlpha), the (.nav-link) for the second tab (#idBeta) remains active. This should not be. I put a "`**_**`" around the active classes and the one designated with : `_**active**_` is the issue.

```
<div id="ordersOutput" style="display: block;">
      <div role="tabpanel">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="orderResultTabs" role="tablist">
                  <li class="nav-item **active**"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#idAlpha" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="false">idAlpha</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link _**active**_" data-toggle="tab" href="#idBeta" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="false">idBeta</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content clearfix">
                  <div class="tab-pane **active**" id="idAlpha" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="tab">
                              <div class="col">
                                    <table class="table table-sm table-responsive" id="orderOutput">
                                    </table>
                                    <form role="form" lpformnum="2">
                                    </form>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="idBeta" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="tab">
                              <div class="col">
                                    <table class="table table-sm table-responsive" id="orderOutput">
                                    </table>
                                    <form role="form" lpformnum="3">
                                    </form>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

The most recent tab should not remain active. Once it is outputted the tabs should return back to normal bootstrap functionality.

Comment: Please include the code for the AJAX call which appends elements. It seems like it would be easiest to; on AJAX success, make all links inactive, then add the new link as active. Instead of adding the new link, then monkeying around with complicated parent child selectors...

Comment: @varlogtim -- i updated the OP with your request. There's a function orderLoop() being called for each entry in the response from the ajax call.

Comment: It looks like the `orderLoop()` function is what actually inserts the new `<li>` elements into the `#orderResultTabs` `<ul>` - is that correct?

Comment: You are correct. I added it to the OP. Take a look.

Comment: I figured since both the nav-item and nav-link needed to be set to active, I'd have to traverse the tree (hope i said that right).

Comment: I just noticed that the `<li>` items and the `<a>` have class=active. Do you need both the `li` and the `a` set to not active?

Comment: Yea, bootstrap adds extra styling to the list item to show that it is indeed active.

Comment: Cool, my answer adds the active tag to both. Have you had a chance to test it?

Comment: @varlogtim your answer does add the active tag to both, however when I click the first tab or any tab other than the most recent, it gets the active tab, but the most recent tab remains active as well. I have added it to my OP to highlight what happens after each ajax call and the behavior of the tabs. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you should first remove the active class from all the elements then assign it to the last one.

```
   $("#orderResultTabs > li > a").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $("#orderResultTabs > li > a:last").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer is to iterate over all the `li > a` items and remove the "active" classes, then set the active class on the last.

I noticed that both the `li` and the `a` have active flags, so that may be causing some confusion. My answer removes the active flag on both the `li` item and the `a` elements.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "orders",
    data: "order_id=" + orderID + "&flag=" + flag,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // var table = $("#orderOutput");
        var tabNav = $("#orderResultTabs");
        var tabContent = $('.tab-content');
        for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            orderID = data[i].orders_id;
            orderLoop(i, data, tabNav, orderID, tabContent);
        }
        $('.loader').hide(); //hide loader
        $('.clear').show();

        // start fix
        $("#orderResultTabs > li").each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $(this).children("a").removeClass("active");
        });

        //$("#orderResultTabs > li:last").addClass("active");
        $("#orderResultTabs > li:last > a").addClass("active");
        // end fix


        $("input[type=orderID]").val("");
        $('#ordersOutput').show();

    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('error');
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your fix works for me. However, when I click any other tab it doesn't set it as active. See my update to the original post. Thanks btw your help. I was stuck on this all day. Glad to have at least that part working.

Comment: Try commenting out the `$("#orderResultTabs > li:last").addClass("active");` ... looking at the `orderLoop()` function again, it appears that when it adds the `li`, they are not active but the `a` elements are.

Comment: your answer does add the active tag to both, however when I click the first tab or any tab other than the most recent, it gets the active tab, but the most recent tab remains active as well. I have added it to my OP to highlight what happens after each ajax call and the behavior of the tabs. Thanks for your help!